# why can't i push this transaction?

Tags: transactions, transaction-verification

Why can't I push this transaction using blockchain.info but a transaction just like mine was broadcasted and mined?

My transaction:

```
0100000001f15c0393d76d26632f9416040a8205da1ff2e294e3ab793425fc95f51a249d3600000000020151ffffffff01301b0f000000000017a9143dbbda49ccc09591516be148dd966610f254e4bc8700000000
```

Similar/Same transaction:

```
01000000017742f03fc00dc2ef74a01b62cf1eabcad12f408497d04f2db256c0a9e4b8a93d00000000020151ffffffff0120402c00000000001976a914d19518b71f7603304c81b69dfb8757bb72d117b788ac00000000
```

Answer (score 2):

Your transaction input has no signature, and it's spending an output sent to address `1BitcoinEaterAddressDontSendf59kuE`. Spending such an output requires an input that contains a signature created with the corresponding private key for that address.

In contrast, the other transaction you're referring to sends to a P2SH address `3MaB7QVq3k4pQx3BhsvEADgzQonLSBwMdj`. This address is a hash of the script "OP_TRUE", which doesn't require any signatures (or anything at all; anyone can spend coins send to that address).